# A common problem in Combinatorial Analysis

Tags: combinatorics

Please help me prove the fact below:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{n+x} = \frac{N!}{\prod_{n=1}^N (n+x)}.
$$
I think this problem is common, but it is really hard for me to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{N! \over n!\pars{N - n}!}\,
>      {\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,n \over n + x}
>      ={N! \over \prod_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}\pars{n + x}}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}{N! \over n!\pars{N - n}!}\,{\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,n \over n + x}}
=-\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{N}{N \choose n}\,{\pars{-1}^{n}}
+x\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{N}{N \choose n}\,{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n + x}
\\[5mm]&=-\bracks{1 + \pars{-1}}^{N}
+x\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{N}{N \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n + x - 1}\,\dd t
=x\int_{0}^{1}t^{x - 1}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{N}{N \choose n}\pars{-t}^{n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=x\int_{0}^{1}t^{x - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{N}\,\dd t
=x\,{\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{N + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{x + N + 1}}
={N! \over \Gamma\pars{x + 1 + N}/\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}
={N! \over \pars{x + 1}^{\rm\pars{N}}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{N! \over \prod_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}\pars{n + x}}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\pars{a}^{\rm\pars{m}}}$ is one of the [Pochhammer Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol): The raising factorial.

Answer (score 4):

It is a straightforward consequence of the residue theorem. The rational function:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\prod_{n=1}^{N}(x+n)} $$
has simple poles in $x=-1,-2,\ldots,-N$, hence:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{c_j}{x+j} $$
where:
$$ c_j = \operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),z=-j\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Jack's answer, multiply both sides by $\dfrac{\prod_{n=1}^N (x+n)}{N!}$ and you get an equality of polynomials of degree at most $N$, and show that the equality is true for $x=0,-1,-2,\dots,-N$.

The cases $x=-1,\dots,-N$, the left hand side is zero for all but one term. which you can check easily.

The case $x=0$ reduces to the binomial theorem for $(1+(-1))^N$, specifically:

$$1-\left(1+(-1)\right)^N = 1$$

A possible inductive proof would write the left hand side as $f_N(x)$ and then you'd get that you want to show that:

$$f_N(x) = \frac{N}{N+x} f_{N-1}(x)$$